# WPF Prism Module Initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-6

I have a Prism Shell with two modules. One module is supposed to be the main application mock, `MainAppMock`, and the other module is supposed to be whatever that main system is using as a region, `ModuleOne`. Could be one, could be a million module.

The issue is understanding how Prism works. The `MainAppModule` initializes properly unless I call it's namespace in the `Bootstrapper` `MainWindow.xaml` file.

My question: Is this because it is loading the module at run time when I am calling that namespace and therefore `Prism` doesn't load it because it is already loaded? What is actually happening behind the scenes?

Shell:

```
class Bootstrapper : NinjectBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Kernel.Get<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new DirectoryModuleCatalog
        {
            ModulePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
        };
    }
}
```

MainAppMock and ModuleOne are the same except for the name.

ModuleOne Class:

```
[Module(ModuleName = "ModuleOne.Module")]
public class Module : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public Module(IRegionManager regionManager, IKernel kernel)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is here. In the `Bootstrapper` `MainWindow`:

```
<Window x:Class="PrismTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns:mainAppMock="clr-namespace:MainAppMock;assembly=MainAppMock"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <mainAppMock:MainUserControl />
</Grid>
```

Note: It works fine if I remove the `mainAppMock` namespace as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing this with a few people we've reached one conclusion.

We are loading the `MainAppMock` by calling it's `namespace:MainUserControl` in the `Shell` `MainWindow`. When Prism's bootstrapper runs it will go in the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and search through the DLLs for anything that inherits from `IModule`. It realizes that `MainAppMock` does that, but it is already loaded. It does not make sense to load a DLL that has already been loaded. Therefore, it won't reload it and the `Module` will never run.

It is worth mentioning that the `MainAppMock` initialization method is running when the DLL is loaded. We can actually do our Prism `Module` code there, but that is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Prism has `Modules` and `Shell`. Let's imagine that `Shell` is TV-Set, consequently, `Modules` will be channels in TV-Set. At start of program (you turn-on TV-Set) in the method `protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()`, you are loading `Modules`(TV-Set loads your searched channels):

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
   ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
   catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleZooModule));//Channel about Zoo
   catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleSportModule));//Channel about Sport
   catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleProgrammingModule));//Channel about Programming
   return catalog;
}
```

And usually `Shell` should look like this:

```
<DockPanel >            
   <ContentControl Margin="5"
        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ContentRegion}"
        prism:RegionManager.RegionManager="{Binding RegionManager}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The row `prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ContentRegion}"` shows to `Prism` where `Module`(video stream of channel) should be injected in your `Shell`(TV-Set).

But in your case is not eligible to use such things:

```
<Grid>
    <mainAppMock:MainUserControl />
</Grid>
```

As `Prism` does not know where `Module`(some channel) can be shown in your `Shell`(TV-Set).

Comment: The third part of your answer isn't true. Prism loads any modules it finds that implement IModule regardless of them being called in a region or not. Furthermore, the regions are simply to call the views, not the Module class.

Note that I am telling Prism that my modules will be located at AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory so it already knows they exist.

Comment: @AzzamAziz yeah, `Prism` loads `Modules` if you write the code inside of `CreateModuleCatalog`. However, Prism does not know where `Module` should be shown in `Shell` without `RegionManager`.

Comment: Which is fine because I am not trying to show it just yet, I am just trying to make sure it loads. The problem isn't that it isn't showing. It's that it isn't loading.

Comment: @AzzamAziz Module is already loaded. You can see it using debugger in `CreateModuleCatalog` method. However, `View` of your module is not injected as you paste this code `<mainAppMock:MainUserControl />` inside of Shell(TV-Set). Prism does not know where Module should be shown in Shell without RegionManager

Comment: Nope. The Module isn't loading. That is why I am asking the question. Write the code and debug it. The MainAppMock will not load.